# MySQL - ordering by column with many different values in big table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

Probably through poor database design, the following really simple query is taking ~1.5 minutes to run.

```
SELECT  s.title, t.name AS team_name
    FROM  stories AS s
    JOIN  teams AS t  ON s.team_id = t.id
    WHERE  s.pubdate >= "1970-01-01 00:00"
    ORDER BY  s.hits /* <-- here's the problem */
    LIMIT  3 OFFSET 0
```

The problem is the `stories` table is fairly big, with ~1.5m rows, and there's a ton of unique values for `hits` (this column logs the hits to each story.)

Take out the order clause and it resolves almost instantly.

Question: what can I do to optimise for queries like this? Presumably I shouldn't apply an index to `hits` since direct no look-ups take place on that column.

[UPDATE]

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all tables concerned:

```
CREATE TABLE stories (
 `id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `link` text NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `pubdate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `source_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `team_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `hits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Unique combo (title + date)` (`title`,`pubdate`),
 KEY `team (FK)` (`team_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE teams (
 `id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `is_live` enum('y') DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `short_name` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
 `server` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `url_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `league` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `away_game_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `digest_list_id` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `twitter_handle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `no_official_news` enum('y') DEFAULT NULL,
 `alt_names` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `no_use_nickname` enum('y') DEFAULT NULL,
 `official_hashtag` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `merge_news_and_fans` enum('y') DEFAULT NULL,
 `colour_1` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `colour_2` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `colour_3` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `link_colour_modifier` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `alt_link_colour_modifier` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `title_shade` enum('dark','light') NOT NULL,
 `shirt_style` enum('vert_stripes','horiz_stripes','vert_stripes_thin','horiz_stripes_thin','vert_split','horiz_split') DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `URL token` (`url_token`),
 KEY `league (FK)` (`league`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Add column aliases so we know were the rows are coming from.

Comment: `I shouldn't apply an index to hits since direct no look-ups take place on that column.` can you please elaborate on this? i'm having trouble understanding it

Comment: You should definitely apply an index. Why not? Try it and see what happens.

Comment: How frequently is `hits` being `UPDATEd`?  If it is often, then the added index will slow down the updates _some_.  Still, it may be worth having `INDEX(hits)` because of the `SELECT`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables. -- _We need to know which table contains `hits`_ plus other things.

Comment: Updated to show table creation code. Thanks for the replies. I'm not the hottest DB programmer so I was under the impression `hits` didn't need an index partly for the reason @RickJames points out, but also because (however erroneous this logic may be) it's not referenced as as foreign key, but only in an `order by`. I'll see if adding an index helps.

Comment: Interesting -- how are you setting `id` in each table?  Not `AUTO_INCREMENT`??

Comment: An index on an `ORDER BY` column will speed up the query. Doesn't matter if the column is being `SELECT`ed or not.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I've learned some stuff here. @RickJames - no, not AI - it's part of a CMS which generates unique hashes for IDs itself.

Comment: Ouch!  Hashes make terrible ids _when the table gets too big to cache_.

Comment: Interesting. I thought this was commonplace. YouTube vids have ID hashes, for example? Is AI really the only sensible way to do IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing the filter on pubdate if the user does not need it.  It confuses the optimizer.

```
INDEX(hits, pubdate, title)
```

will probably help the query the most.  It is "covering".

The reason why removing `ORDER BY` runs fast:  Without it, it gives you *any* 3 rows.  With it, and without a useful index, it needs to sort the 1.5M rows to discover the 3 with the least number of hits.

Perhaps you wanted `ORDER BY s.hits DESC`? -- to get those with the *most* hits.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful.